# IClassFactory error when creating a late bound COM object from ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, com, iis-10

I am in the process of setting up a ASP.NET website on a Windows Server 2016.  The  website also creates instances of COM objects using the following C# code:

```
    Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(ProgID, Server, true);
    dynamic object = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

However, the program throws an exception on the line `Activator.CreateInstance` with the following error:

```
Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {E2FB185E-F4D8-482A-B27B-A08BB4F9EAE9} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 800a0005 Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A0005 (CTL_E_ILLEGALFUNCTIONCALL).
```

I do not get this error when installing on a Server 2012 machine.  Also, I am able to run this code without error on the 2016 server if I run it as a Window's App under the same user account that the Application Pool uses.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem was in the COM object which was written in VB6.  The underlying error was "Invalid procedure call or argument". The error happened because of a missing System environment variable which needed by the application.  The variables were defined on the user level but they don't load for the user that the application pool uses.

The error went away as soon as I added the missing environment variables for the system.